# How to format date field output to be "___ Days until" using Drupal 7 Date & Views module

Tags: drupal, date, drupal-views

I have a "Deadline" field in a custom content type.

I am using views to display an output of my nodes and their respective deadlines. But I want the deadline to be a numeric days until, or "109", instead of "dec 8, 2011".

Using the Date module, I am having a hard time understanding how to parse my results such that they are how I want. There is a formatter "time ago" - but outputs in the style "1 week, 5 days to go"..

I know very little about tokens, or styling the content, but perhaps there is an answer in that.

Any solution which utilizes Views "Configure field: Field: Deadline" would be clean and preferable!

Answer (score -1):

do you mean that you want the result of dead line field to tell you the number of days remaining to the deadline ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Result as in the finial output. Obviously this will change day to day.

Comment: ok i modified a module to fit ur requirements
http://Bazo0ka.com/date-field.zip
good luck

Comment: How do I use this? - Also, will this allow me to also pull the normal date deadline from the same field?

Comment: this module will create a new field do the following

* enable the module * add the field that the module generated to ur content type * this field is the deadline date ....try this and tell me if its working

Comment: please tell me if its worked with you or not...if its worked with you please make this answer as the correct answer...good luck

Comment: this did not work, it did not quite address my problem. I am working in VIEWS, and using the 'time ago' format, would like to only display the number of days until, or since the deadline. Are there tokens I can use for this?

Comment: are you tested this module...this module generate a new field like what date module do... but when you display this date field the result will not be the date itself but it will be the number of days...are you tested this module field ?

Comment: When I display it in VIEWS, and go to format this field, it displays there?

Comment: suppose that my module name is "Date Duration" module... to use this module .. first go to you content type and delete the  field of "Date" module...and install my module...go to you content type again..you will find a new field called "Date and time field" this field is generated by "Date Duration" module...

summary: This module Create A new field like what Date module do..just remove "Date" module Field and use the field that generated by this module

good luck